# What does squid-cgi package do?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, squid

I have installed `squid-cgi` package. What next? No any references to `cachamgr.cgi` appeared in Apache configs. File `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/cachemgr.cgi` appeared in the system. Should I refer it manually in configs?

Answer (score 0):

It provides a web interface to [the Squid cache manager](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheManager). See [the Squid Wiki](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ManagerCgiTool) for instructions on setting it up.